# How do I update an object that hasn't been saved without saving it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So I am doing this:

```
@portfolio = current_user.portfolio
@port_stock = PortStock.new(port_stock_params)
stock = Stock.find(port_stock_params[:stock_id])
@port_stock.update!(current_price: stock.price)

respond_to do |format|
  if @port_stock.save
```

The issue I am having is that when I call `.update!` on `@port_stock` it actually saves the record before `@port_stock.save` later.

So my callbacks are being executed twice, which is messing up stuff in my DB.

So how do I update the `new` instance of `@port_stock.current_price` without actually saving the `@port_stock` object before I call it explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're only updating one attribute, you could just use the setter:

```
@port_stock.current_price = stock.price
```

Or you could do:

```
stock = Stock.find(port_stock_params[:stock_id])
@port_stock = PortStock.new(port_stock_params.merge(current_price: stock.price))
```

Comment: Not sure why the simple setter didn't occur to me, but thanks for the tip! The `.merge` is also great.

Answer (score 8):

Try [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes), it accepts an hash as parameter and don't hit the database, it works just on the object

```
@port_stock.assign_attributes(current_price: stock.price)
```

Obviously, if you want just update one field, @Sergio's answer is better and simpler

Comment: This is awesome, but I agree that @Sergio's answer is better and simpler. Thanks for this though!